Grouping Dimension only data into a graph in Marketing Intelligence(Datorama)
I have some dimension only tables in my MCI(Datorama) instance on which I would like to aggregate on, in the form of a graph.
For example, I have a table of patients(identified uniquely by patient id). In this table there is a "Segment" column which can have 1 of 3 values ( Lead, Converted, NotConverted).
Basically, in a bar graph, I would like to show the count of rows grouped by segment(e.g 40 leads, 20 converted, 30 NotConverted).
Is this possible in MCI(Datorama)?
Below is a screenshot of how I'm currently setting up the dimension and measurement:

Here are the settings for the calculated measurement:


And right before I save, I get the following alert:

In the end, the resulting bar graph is still empty. What could I be doing wrong?
